# Using fopen to write lines of text into a txt file php

Tags: php, html

I'm having a problem with PHP when trying to use the `fopen` to write lines of text inside of a `textarea` to a `.txt` file. Here's my code, hopefully someone can help!

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
        $_SESSION['msg'] = "You must log in first";
        header('location: login.php');
    }
    if (isset($_GET['logout'])) {
        session_destroy();
        unset($_SESSION['username']);
        header("location: login.php");
    }
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
    $file = "extra/" . $username . ".png";
    if (!file_exists($file)) $file = 'extra/defaultProfile.png';
    function sendData($u) {
        $myfile = fopen('bio/' . $username . '.txt', $u);
    }
?>
<html>
    <title> Home Page </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="downloads.php">Downloads</a></li>
                    <li><a href="chat.php">Chat</a></li>
                    <li><a href="profile.php">Profile</a></li>
                    <li class="logout"><a href="index.php?logout='1'">Logout</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
    <body>
        <div class="profileimg">
            <img src=<?php echo $file; ?>  width="125" height="125">
        </div>
        <div class="profilename">
            <p style="position: absolute; top: 8px; left: 130px; color: white; font-size: 30px;"><?php echo $username ?></p>
        </div>
        <div class="biotext">
            <form action="" method="post">
                <textarea name="lines" width=25% height=9.5% background-color='white' style="position: absolute; top: 75px; left: 132.5px;"></textarea>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" formaction="sendData()"/>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
    <footer>
        <div class="status">Currently logged in as <?php echo $username ?></div>
    </footer>
</html>
```

I've tried everything that could come up but I can't seem to find the right solution... I tried making and using a function called `sendData()` but that didn't work either. Any help anyone can provide is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Have a look at the documentation: http://php.net/manual/de/function.fopen.php

Comment: `formaction="sendData()"` what is this?

Comment: I have never used formaction attribute ever but you are calling "sendData()" function without any parameter, also shouldn't you be using : $myfile = fopen('bio/' . $username . '.txt', w), instead of $myfile = fopen('bio/' . $username . '.txt', $u)??

Answer (score 1):

1. check if the file exist
2. check if permission is granted to write the file
3. sendData() its php and you call it from html
4. you forgot declare this variable = $u when you call the function

you can do something like this:

```
<?php
  if (!empty($_POST))
  {
    $text_data = $_POST['text_data'];
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    fopen('bio/' . $username . '.txt', $text_data);
  }
?>
<html>
<title> Home Page </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
<header>
    <div class="container">
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="downloads.php">Downloads</a></li>
          <li><a href="chat.php">Chat</a></li>
          <li><a href="profile.php">Profile</a></li>
          <li class="logout"><a href="index.php?logout='1'">Logout</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
<body>
  <div class="profileimg">
    <img src=<?php echo $file; ?>  width="125" height="125">
  </div>
  <div class="profilename">
    <p style="position: absolute; top: 8px; left: 130px; color: white; font-size: 30px;"><?php echo $username ?></p>
  </div>
    <div class="biotext">
        <form action="" method="post">
        <textarea name="lines" width=25% height=9.5% background-color='white' style="position: absolute; top: 75px; left: 132.5px;"></textarea>
        <input type="text" name="text_data" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="username" value="<?php echo $username ?>">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
<footer>
<div class="status">Currently logged in as <?php echo $username ?></div>
</footer>
</html>
```

Comment: For some reason, this does not work. It wont replace any of the text inside the file...